# xsl cdata-section-elements output property with Xalan-J

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan

I'm trying to output a CDATA section in the result of XSLT using Xalan 2.7.1.  I have applied this XSL to the XML in a tool and the result contains CDATA.  In the method below, no CDATA is in the result and no exception is thrown.  I feel like I'm missing something here.

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parentelem>
    <childelem>Test text</childelem>
</parentelem>
```

**test.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" cdata-section-elements="newchildelem" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<parentelem>
    <newchildelem><xsl:value-of select="/parentelem/childelem" /></newchildelem>
</parentelem>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Transform.java**

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource;

public class Transform {

    public static void main (String[] args){
    try {
        XMLStreamReader xmlReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(
            new FileReader("test.xml"));

        XMLStreamReader xslReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(
                new FileReader("test.xsl"));

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslSource = new StAXSource(xslReader);
        Source xmlSource = new StAXSource(xmlReader);
        Transformer transf = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xslSource);

        StringWriter xmlString = new StringWriter();
        XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(
                xmlString);

        Result transformedXml = new StAXResult(xmlWriter);
        transf.transform(xmlSource, transformedXml);

        xmlWriter.flush();
        System.out.println(xmlString.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**console output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><parentelem><newchildelem>Test text</newchildelem></parentelem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I guess it turns out i haven't been using Xalan 2.7.1.  The code in [skaffman's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065200/xsl-cdata-section-elements-output-property-with-xalan-j/1065428#1065428) answer made me think to check Version.getVersion() and the signature is "XL TXE Java 1.0.7".  This appears to be the default when using IBM java [IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, J2RE 1.6.0)].

2) I switched from using StAXSource and StAXResult to using StreamSource and StreamResult and it works fine (like in [skaffman's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065200/xsl-cdata-section-elements-output-property-with-xalan-j/1065428#1065428) answer).  Specifically the change from StAXResult to StreamResult is what worked.  Using StAXSource with StreamResult works too.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you want to output the CDATA as part of the element?

```
<newchildelem><xsl:value-of select="/parentelem/childelem" /></newchildelem>
```

with

```
<newchildelem><xsl:text>&lt;![CDATA[
</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/parentelem/childelem" /><xsl:text>]]&gt</xsl:text></newchildelem>
```

or some other form, but with the escaped characters to omit

```
<newchildelem><![CDATA[Test text]]></newchildelem>
```

or am I misunderstanding the question perhaps?

Comment: that is what i'd like to do and your solution works.  i thought that i could use the cdata-section-elements here to achieve the same thing.  using the cdata-section-elements approach works when i apply the above xsl to the above xml in an XML tool, i get the desired result.  only when I use the above code to apply the xsl do i not get the expected result

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, with Xalan 2.7.1, not sure why it doesn't work for you.

I simplified the code fragment, but I don't think there's any functional difference, but try it anyway:

```
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.apache.xalan.Version;

public class Transform {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Version.getVersion());
        Source xslSource = new StreamSource(Transform.class.getResourceAsStream("test.xsl"));
        Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(Transform.class.getResourceAsStream("test.xml"));

        Transformer transf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xslSource);

        StreamResult transformedXml = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transf.transform(xmlSource, transformedXml);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Xalan Java 2.4.1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parentelem><newchildelem><![CDATA[Test text]]></newchildelem></parentelem>
```

What is odd is that Xalan's Version.getVersion() returns 2.4.1, not 2.7.1, and I'm *definitely* using 2.7.1 here.